# How to map positions to grid and back?

Tags: c#, .net, geometry

So I have a space say int(from 0 to 990). I want to map all ponts in it to 30 items grid and back. [This is](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J292vw) wnat I came up with.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static int MapToGrid(int pos = 123)
    {
        var xfactor = 990 / 29;
        return pos / xfactor;
    }

    public static float MapToSpace(int idx = 10)
    {
        var xfactor = 990 / 30;
        return (float)(idx * xfactor) + xfactor * 0.5f;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine((990 / 30).ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(MapToGrid(990).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(MapToGrid(0).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(MapToGrid(34).ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(MapToSpace(1).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(MapToSpace(0).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(MapToSpace(29).ToString());
    }
}
```

Resuts seem to be correct but I cant just wrap my head around that `29` and `30` magic numbers... Can any one explain how to map positions to grid and back?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"I want to map all ponts in it to 30 items grid and back."*. How did you arrive at those numbers if you don't understand them?

Comment: They felt appropriate - arrays start from 0 to 29 there will be 30 Items. So this is where I got 29 and 30, yet I really can not get why it all works Ok... Feels more like holistic programming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple high school algebra. Say you have a grid of size `W` (= 990 in example) and number of cells `N` (= 30):

- `MapToGrid` returns the *index* (range `[0, N - 1]`) of the cell which the coordinate `p` falls into

  The *normalized coordinate* is given by `p / W` (range `[0, 1]`), so the index is this times the maximum index (`N - 1`). Therefore the formula is `index = p * (N - 1) / W`, where `(N - 1) / W = 1 / xfactor`.
- `MapToSpace` returns the midpoint of this cell

  `W / N = xfactor` is the width of each cell. Therefore the left boundary of cell `index` is given by `index * xfactor`. Add `0.5 * xfactor` (i.e. half the width) to this to get the midpoint.